# "There was no endpoint listening " This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action

Tags: c#, wcf

I have created the wcf service. I added the service using "add service refence" in vs2017.
after adding the service i am trying to access using below function (c#)

```
List<ProductData> data = new List<ProductData>();                    
ServiceReferenceIHS.PriceClient ns = new ServiceReferenceIHS.PriceClient();
 data = ns.GetPricesData(clientName, password, lstISHCode.ToArray(), Startdate, EndDate).ToList();
```

I am providing the values to `GetPricesData` method.
below  is the exception message.

```
There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:8080/Test.svc that could accept the message. 
This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. 
See InnerException, if present, for more details.
```

The inner exception is `Unable to connect to the remote server`

this is the appconfig configuration.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IPrice" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:8080/Test.svc"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IPrice"
          contract="ServiceReferenceIHS.IPrice" name="BasicHttpBinding_IPrice" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

what is wrong in my code.

Comment: it looks like you haven't started the service on your machine.

Comment: Is your service up and running while you are trying to access ?

Comment: @Butler1233 service is running. but when i am creating solution separate solution it is working fine.